# Animate a layout to the bottom of another layout whose distance is determined at runtime

Tags: android, animation, translation

I have two `FrameLayout`s overlapping each other(let's call them `layout_front` and `layout_back`, where each layout has multiple text and image views). Initially `layout_back`'s visibility is set to gone.

**What I want to achieve**: When I want the `layout_back` to display, I set it to visible, and  I want to animate the layout_front to slide down to the bottom of layout_back. The effect would be like I have two "cards",sliding down the front card to show another card at the back.

**Problem:** The first obvious way to do it is by creating a animation xml for `layout_front` like this :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

1) My first problem is, the `layout_front` won't stay in there after animation, but popped back to its original position immediately after the translation. What should I do to make it *stay* there after sliding down?

2) My second problem is more serious. The distance for `layout_front` to slide (which is the height of the `layout_back`) is not determined until runtime. Is there any way to dynamically set the value YDelta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer this myself. The layout would look something like this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pair_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@id/layout_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/list_background"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@id/layout_front"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background">

            <Button
                android:id="@id/button_blue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </Button>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The layout at back consists of a textview while the layout in front is a button. When the button is clicked, it will slide to the bottom of textview. The button listener is implemented like this:

```
public class ButtonListener implements OnClickListener {
    final FrameLayout l_front;
    final FrameLayout l_back;

    public blueListener(FrameLayout f, FrameLayout b) {
        this.l_back = b;
        this.l_front = f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        l_back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        l_back.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        l_front.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        TranslateAnimation tanim = new TranslateAnimation(
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f,
                TranslateAnimation.ABSOLUTE, l_back.getMeasuredHeight());
        tanim.setDuration(400);
        tanim.setFillAfter(true);
        tanim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        l_front.setAnimation(tanim);
        ((RelativeLayout)l_front.getParent()).getLayoutParams().height
        = l_back.getMeasuredHeight() + l_front.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```